# How to remove hard coded IP address from connection.py file. (I'm very very new to this)

Tags: python, django, static-ip-address

Can someone tell me how to remove an IP address that has been hard coded in a connection.py file?
We were told to Check settings.py for database connection settings
its common practice to have settings.py include another file like settings_local.py for environment specific configuration.
There is no settings_local.py.  Could this file be hidden or just doesn't exist?
If it doesn't exist can it be created with the hopes of removing what is hard coded.

```
`/src/mongoengine/mongoengine/connection.py", line 126, in get_connection
    raise ConnectionError("Cannot connect to database %s :\n%s" % (alias, e))
    mongoengine.connection.ConnectionError: Cannot connect to database default :
    enter code here`could not connect to ip-10-171-58-44.ec2.internal:27017: timed out
```

Comment: There is no hard coded IP anywhere in Django.

Comment: Go to your project's root folder and do `grep -r . -e ip-10-171-58-44.ec2.internal`

Answer (score 1):

By default, mongoengine will try to connect to localhost. It is not finding a mongo instance there, which is the source of your error.

The `ip-10-141-58-44.ec2.internal` is just the hostname of the server; it is not hardcoded anywhere.

Have a look at your `settings.py` file, there should be a line such as:

```
connect('somenamehere')
```

Where 'somenamehere' is the name of your database; if such a line exists, then it is trying to connect to a mongo on the localhost.

Now you have two choices:

1. Setup mongo on your localhost.
2. Update `settings.py` and point it to the location of your mongo database installation. You can do this by passing in an extra parameter `host`, `connect('somenamehere', host='10.10.10.1')`. See the [documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/connecting.html#guide-connecting) for more information.